# Zelix Klasmaster FATAL_ERROR Java Obfuscation

Tags: java

I'm using Zelix Klassmaster to obfuscate my JAR file. For the classpath settings, I've added rt.jar, along with all other JDK libs. However, after selecting my class files, Zelix always encounters the same error:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\rt.jar!javax/swing/JComponent.class : "Class file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\lib\rt.jar!javax/swing/JComponent.class' is corrupt. Tag '15' at 1622 is invalid" : File is probably corrupt
```

This error also occurs with the Map$Entry.class, and maybe with a few others.
I've tried reinstalling my JDK, but that hasn't solved the problem. Does anyone know why this happens, and how I can fix it? Currently, I can only obfuscate projects that aren't using java.util.Map and javax.swing.JComponent. This is really frustrating, and a solution would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 8 introduced some significant changes to the Java class file format.  In particular, the JVM "invokedynamic" instruction now appears in the bootstrap classes.  Zelix KlassMaster 5 cannot process Java 8 bytecode.  Support for Java 8 bytecode was introduced in Zelix KlassMaster 6.0.  There are no real workarounds for this other than not using Java 8 or upgrading your version of Zelix KlassMaster.

Comment: Thanks for the reply buddy! :D There aren't many people who know about things like this, and your reply really made my day. Keep up the good work and thanks for helping me with my question! :D